# angles of a star

Tags: pattern

I want to make a star with 2" x 2".
I know that there are 10 equal length sides.
What I need to know is what angle am I to cut each piece at: the tip of the star, and the outside "V" of the star. A chop saw cut angles to 45 degrees.

Comment: The first part of your question is just asking for angles on a regular 5-point star. Your last sentence, though, introduces an angle that doesn't appear on any internal or external angle. Are you asking how to construct the 5-point star angles using just a 45-degree tool?

Answer (score 0):

1. Label your corners clockwise $A, B, C, D$.
2. On side $AB$, mark the half-way point $P_{AB}$ at 1".
3. Cut from $P_{AB}$ towards the adjacent sides $BC$, creating $P_{BC}$ where the cut meet the edge. The angle $P_{BC}P_{AB}P_B$ is $54^{\circ}$.
4. Cut from $P_{BC}$ to edge $CD$, creating $P_{CD}$. The angle $P_{AB}P_{BC}P_{CD}$ is $72^{\circ}$.
5. Mirror the two cuts you just made on the other side of the material.

You now have a pentagon. Draw lines connecting all vertices of this pentagon and cut out the pieces that will leave you with a star.